# What's wrong with this storage calculator?

Tags: python

I'm new to python, and this question appeared on a course.

```
def calculate_storage(filesize):
    block_size = 4096
    # Use floor division to calculate how many blocks are fully occupied
    full_blocks = filesize // block_size
    # Use the modulo operator to check whether there's any remainder
    partial_block_remainder = filesize % block_size
    # Depending on whether there's a remainder or not, return
    # the total number of bytes required to allocate enough blocks
    # to store your data.
    if partial_block_remainder > 0:
        return full_blocks+1
    return full_blocks

print(calculate_storage(1))    # Should be 4096
print(calculate_storage(4096)) # Should be 4096
print(calculate_storage(4097)) # Should be 8192
print(calculate_storage(6000)) # Should be 8192
```

This was my answer. The question was this:
[If a filesystem has a block size of 4096 bytes, this means that a file comprised of only one byte will still use 4096 bytes of storage. A file made up of 4097 bytes will use 4096*2=8192 bytes of storage. Knowing this, can you fill in the gaps in the calculate_storage function below, which calculates the total number of bytes needed to store a file of a given size?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYval.png)

With the base code here:

```
def calculate_storage(filesize):
    block_size = 4096
    # Use floor division to calculate how many blocks are fully occupied
    full_blocks = ___
    # Use the modulo operator to check whether there's any remainder
    partial_block_remainder = ___
    # Depending on whether there's a remainder or not, return
    # the total number of bytes required to allocate enough blocks
    # to store your data.
    if partial_block_remainder > 0:
        return ___
    return ___

print(calculate_storage(1))    # Should be 4096
print(calculate_storage(4096)) # Should be 4096
print(calculate_storage(4097)) # Should be 8192
print(calculate_storage(6000)) # Should be 8192
```

[The Incorrect statement was this:
Not quite. One concept to keep in mind is the difference
between float division (/) and floor division (//). Floor
division rounds down to the nearest whole number, which is
useful for this question. Use filesize // block_size to get
the amount of full blocks. Something else to remember here
is the format of modulo arithmetic. The divisor is always to
the right of the modulo operator. E.g.- 2 = 6 % 4 <- This is
the divisor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyyKf.png)

Comment: The feedback you received looks like it was canned and not specific to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to multiply the return values by the block size:

```
def calculate_storage(filesize):
    block_size = 4096
    # Use floor division to calculate how many blocks are fully occupied
    full_blocks = filesize // block_size
    # Use the modulo operator to check whether there's any remainder
    partial_block_remainder = filesize % block_size
    # Depending on whether there's a remainder or not, return
    # the total number of bytes required to allocate enough blocks
    # to store your data.
    if partial_block_remainder > 0:
        return block_size * (full_blocks + 1)
    return block_size * full_blocks

print(calculate_storage(1))    # Should be 4096
print(calculate_storage(4096)) # Should be 4096
print(calculate_storage(4097)) # Should be 8192
print(calculate_storage(6000)) # Should be 8192
```

returns:

```
4096
4096
8192
8192
```